# ORA-12541: TNS:no listener on ubuntu server, oracle instant client

Tags: php, oracle, server, ubuntu-16.04

My oracle db on cloud, PHP code is on ubuntu 16.04 server.
I have installed instant client basic & instant client sdk on ubuntu server.
I am able to connect with oracle DB on cloud using SQL developer.
But when I try to connect my PHP code with oracle db on cloud I get

```
"ORA-12541: TNS:no listener " error message.
```

I am new to Oracle DB. but as per my knowledge if oracle is installed on cloud in a different server, & code is in a different server, then the listener is not required on the client-server.

Please help me with this

Comment: ORA-12541 can mean the server is down or the listener is not started. You say this is not your situation. But it can also indicate network problems, and that seems more  likely. Perhaps you have firewall issues? Maybe your Oracle PATH is wrong? Are you sure you have the correct values in LDAP.ORA / TNSNAMES.ORA / SQLNET,ORA (depending on how you're connecting)?

Comment: On code server listener is not installed

Comment: please post that as an answer and accept it. Questions with accepted answers improve the quality of this site for other Seekers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved after adding wallet file on client-server